# Algorithm to detect curved lines from list of 2D points

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry, image-segmentation, feature-detection

I am trying to extract horizontal lines from a set of 2D points generated from the photo of the model of a human torso:

[image: overal view of torso point cloud]

The points "mostly" form horizontal(ish) lines in a more or less regular way, but with possible gaps/missing-points:

[image: some missing points]

There can be regions where the lines deform a bit:

[image]

And regions with background noise:[image]

Of course I would need to tune things so I exclude those parts with defects. What I am looking for with this question is a suggested algorithm to find lines where they are well-behaved, filling eventual gaps and avoiding eventual noise, and also terminating the lines properly upon some discontinuity condition.

I believe there could be some optimizing or voting "flood fill" variant that would score line candidates and yield only well-formed lines, but I am not experienced with this and cannot figure anything by myself.

This dataset is [in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/heltonbiker/3468362c7dc0fd069be0cda2a2737805), and it is important to note that X coordinates are integers, so points are aligned vertically. The Y coordinates though are decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by finding the nearest neighbor of every dot, then the second nearest neighbor *on the other side* (I mean only considering the dots in the half plane opposite to the first neighbor).

If the distance to the second neighbor exceeds twice the distance to the first, ignore it.

Just doing that, I bet that you will reconstruct a great deal of the curves, with gaps left unfilled.

By estimating the local curvature along the curve (f.i. by computing the circumscribed circle of three dots, taking every other dot, you can discard noisy portions.

Then to fill the gaps, you can detect the curve endpoints and look for the nearest endpoint in an angle around the extrapolated direction.

First step in the processing:

[image]

Comment: This is quite interesting. I thought about doing that but got a bit "paralyzed" by the so many other possibilities I am thinking about. Currently I am reading about "edge linking", and "Hugh transform", they look like important concepts to either close the gaps and discard the non-conformant segments. Thanks so far, expect some feedback from me soon!

Comment: Next trick: some longer links appear. That's because there is no absolute threshold on the distance. You can find one by taking some multiple of the average of the 100 smallest distances.

Answer (score 0):

These are [integral curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) to the vector field representing the direction pattern.

So maybe start by finding for each point the slope vector, the predominant direction, by taking points from the neighborhood and fitting a line with LS or performing a PCA. Increasing the neighborhood radius should allow to deal with the data irregularities thereby picking up a greater-scale slope trend instead of a local noise.

If you decide to do this, could you post here the slope field you find, so instead of points could we see some tangents?

Comment: Hi, rych, thanks for your answer! I am going to think about your suggestions! Currently I am juggling many projects along a single work week, so I'm munching every suggestion I get or figure out to try them (w)holisticaly at some point. Specifically, I thought about taking a given point and somehow figuring the "stripe field slope" for that point, sort of a mapping between the original space and some transformed space where I would find local solutions. Your request for feedback enforces my willingness to do so, thanks again for now!

Comment: Also, I got some field data yesterday (actual photos of backs of actual people) so perhaps I create a larger gist with actual sample data, sort of a sandbox dataset.

Comment: Me again: I read about the integral curves, and they seem to be tightly related to the concept of differential equations. Here I don't have differential equations at all, since these points are extracted from a photo, and there are multiple region types in the image: stripes in background, stripes in subject, shadows without stripes, parts of the subject without stripe incidence, etc.

Comment: In the end, differential equations are usually solved numerically on a grid or a mesh. For missing points or sparse data you could first interpolate the vector data onto a regular dense grid, see for example the article "2009. A divergence-free spatial interpolator for large sparse velocity data sets"

Comment: Yeah, but remember the actual surface is an arbitrary shape (although anatomically model-based) that is not quite a vector field, much less one that could be modeled by parametric equations, and the data-set is composed by points, not vectors. Unless I am failing to see something really smart :o)